# Can't reset WordPress password

Tags: security, password

I haven't logged onto my blog for years, and have, of course, forgotten the password. I click the 'Forgot' button and get a mail with a link, but that mail already says

> Sorry, that key does not appear to be valid.

And sends me round the click to reset, receive a mail, click the link again etc. As if the timeout for password resets has been set to 0.5s or something.

This is a shared hosted blog, so I have full access to cPanel and all of the WP files via FTP, if that helps anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the PHPMyAdmin login and access:

1. The wp_users table from the list of tables.
2. Then locate your username under the user_login column and click edit.
3. The user_pass is a long list of numbers and letters which is the MD5 hash encrypted version of your password.
4. Select and delete the hash and type in your new password (it is case sensitive!).
5. Once you have done that, click the dropdown menu indicated, and select MD5 from the menu.
6. Save the changes and attempt to login.

Since it sounds like your site is very old I would recommend updating the themes and plugins as needed.

Comment: Did this work for you?